# C# (String.StartsWith && !String.EndsWith && !String.Contains) using a List

Tags: c#, string, linq, combinations, startswith

I am a newbie in C#, and I am having problems.

I have 2 List, 2 strings and a getCombinations(string) method that
returns all combinations of a string as List;

How do i validate if a subjectStrings element does not
StartWith && !EndsWith && !Contains (or !StartWith && !EndsWith && Contains, etc.)
for every combinations of startswithString, endswithString and containsString?

Here is my code in StartWith && !EndsWith
(if you want to see it running: http://ideone.com/y8JZkK)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Test
    {
            public static void Main()
            {
                    List<string> validatedStrings = new List<string>();
                    List<string> subjectStrings = new List<string>()
                    {
                            "con", "cot", "eon", "net", "not", "one", "ten", "toe", "ton",
                                    "cent", "cone", "conn", "cote", "neon", "none", "note", "once", "tone",
                                    "cento", "conte", "nonce", "nonet", "oncet", "tenon", "tonne",
                                    "nocent","concent", "connect"
                    }; //got a more longer wordlist

                    string startswithString = "co";
                    string endswithString = "et";

                    foreach(var z in subjectStrings)
                    {
                        bool valid = false;
                        foreach(var a in getCombinations(startswithString))
                        {
                            foreach(var b in getCombinations(endswithString))
                            {
                                if(z.StartsWith(a) && !z.EndsWith(b))
                                {
                                        valid = true;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(valid)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(valid)
                        {
                            validatedStrings.Add(z);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach(var a in validatedStrings)
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine(a);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\nDone");
            }


            static List<string> getCombinations(string s)
            {
                    //Code that calculates combinations
                    return Permutations.Permutate(s);
            }
    }

    public class Permutations
    {
            private static List<List<string>> allCombinations;

            private static void CalculateCombinations(string word, List<string> temp)
            {
                    if (temp.Count == word.Length)
                    {
                            List<string> clone = temp.ToList();
                            if (clone.Distinct().Count() == clone.Count)
                            {
                                    allCombinations.Add(clone);
                            }
                            return;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
                    {
                            temp.Add(word[i].ToString());
                            CalculateCombinations(word, temp);
                            temp.RemoveAt(temp.Count - 1);
                    }
            }

            public static List<string> Permutate(string str)
            {
                    allCombinations = new List<List<string>>();
                    CalculateCombinations(str, new List<string>());
                    List<string> combinations = new List<string>();
                    foreach(var a in allCombinations)
                    {
                            string c = "";
                            foreach(var b in a)
                            {
                                    c+=b;
                            }
                            combinations.Add(c);
                    }
                    return combinations;
            }
    }
```

Output:

```
    con 
    cot
    cone
    conn
    cote <<<
    conte <<<
    concent
    connect

    Done
```

if(z.StartsWith(a) && !z.EndsWith(b))
var b can be "et" and "te", but cote and conte endswith "te",
why it is still added in my validated strings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for such questions you can use recursive functions would you please provide more examples that i understand exactly what the function should return as output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
z.StartsWith(a) && !z.EndsWith(b)
```

check below combination

```
z ="cote"
a ="co"
b ="te"
```

so z start with "co" and z not end with "te", your condition pass and `cote` will add to list

i would try as below

```
var sw =getCombinations(startswithString);
var ew = getCombinations(endswithString);


var result = subjectStrings.Where(z=> 
    sw.Any(x=>z.StartsWith(x) && 
        !ew.Any(y=>z.EndsWith(y))))
        .ToList();
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/nXdQJh)</kbd>

output :

```
con
cot
cone
conn
concent
connect
```

Comment: this worked well in this situation, then tried using it with permutations of "aa" to another List<string> , it doesn't filter invalid strings, found out that my Permutation class doesn't produce any combinations with "aa", so I tried replacing my combinations generator with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
                            foreach(var b in getCombinations(endswithString))
                        {
                            if(z.StartsWith(a) && !z.EndsWith(b))
                            {
                                    valid = true;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
```

here you are setting valid to true as soon as there is match for  !z.EndsWith(b) and you are not traversing the whole list of permutations available. 
since "cote" doesn't end with "et" it is a match and valid is set to true and the code breaks.
So that's why "cote" is added to your list of  valid strings. So is the case with "conte".

What you want to do is :

```
    List<string> startsWithCombination = getCombinations("co");
    List<string> endsWithCombination = getCombinations("et");

    foreach (var z in subjectStrings)
    {
        bool isStartMatchFound = startsWithCombination.Any(b => z.StartsWith(b));

        if (isStartMatchFound)
        {
            bool isEndMatchFound = endsWithCombination.Any(b => z.EndsWith(b));

            if (!isEndMatchFound)
            {
                validatedStrings.Add(z);
            }
        }
    }
```